# How to place all focus appended text at a same, fixed position in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm studying the code made by D3noob for a line chart with mousetracker and tooltip.
This tooltips appear very close to the selected data points.
I am not sure how to do in order to have the tooltip always positionned on the top-left corner of my chart.
The problem here is that the tooltip's coordinates are relative the selected data point's position.

Here is the original link from D3noob:
http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6eb506b129f585ce5c8a

I believe that the portion of the code which needs to be changed is:

```
focus.append("text")
.attr("class", "y2")
.attr("dx", 8)
.attr("dy", "-.3em");

focus.append("text")
.attr("class", "y4")
.attr("dx", 8)
.attr("dy", "1em");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create two selections, one for each text element:

```
var text1 = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y1")
    .style("opacity", 0.8)
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 30);

var text2 = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y3")
    .style("opacity", 0.8)
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 40);
```

And use that in the `mousemove` function:

```
text1.text(d.close);
text2.text(formatDate(d.date));
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/64fd748d63f2a0754afbc5dfc62b75e7